# Requirements to turn the "Achievements" statue golden

Tags: achievements, ios, plants-vs-zombies

On the PC Version there is a way to turn the "broken" statue into a golden one:

[image: Golden statue] **- vs -** [image: Current iPhone Achievements Gnome]

On the iPhone Version I am not able to do so.

The question is: Is there a requirement that I am missing or is it just not possible?

#### What I've done:

- Played through the campaign 3 times.
- Earned **all** the achievements.
- Got all the Trophies from mini-games and puzzles (34 of 34).
- Bought everything from the shop.
- Won all the iZombie & Vasebreaker games and getting to level 10/15 respectively for the achievements.

Anything missing?

Answer (score 6):

You need to also beat all of the Puzzle Mode challenges as well as the survival mode challenges (excluding the infinite ones obviosuly).

Comment: I've beaten all the Puzzles (there are achievements for it so I didn't mention it) and sorry but I'm not aware of any survival mode challenges on the iPhone. Did i miss them? Do you have a golden statue?

Comment: Survival Mode is unlocked after beating Adventure one time.

Answer (score 1):

To clear things up, there is NOT a survival mode on iPhone. And you cannot turn the statue golden on iOS.